# Change style of a tr after verify if content > than 0 in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code which works fine :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function()
    {
            $j('.Grid tr.myid').each(function()
            {
                    var test = $j(this).html().indexOf("0");
                     if (test !=-1) {
                            $j(this).addClass("RowRed");
                     }
            });
    });     

</script>
```

Example in html:

```
<table>
    <tr class='myid'><td>value1</td><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr class='myid'><td>value2</td><td>150</td></tr>
</table>
```

But I need to check if the value of a column in `tr` is < 0, and then change it's background color. With this code I can't, because it's looking for a static value for example JMG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to get the text content of the second `td` elements, instead of `html` you can use `text` method, which returns the text content of an element.

```
$j('.Grid tr.myid').each(function() {
      if ($j('td:eq(1)', this).text() < 0) {
          $j(this).addClass('background')      
      }
});
```

- [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, can you explaind me what's mean this please ? 'td:eq(1)'

Comment: @Russo It selects the second `td` in a `tr` element, I used `$(selector, context)`, `context` is a current `tr` element, and `td:eq(1)` is the second `td` element in that `tr`.

Answer (score 0):

try with selector `:last` and parse (`parseInt`) the text value to int:

```
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function()
    {
            $j('.Grid tr.myid').each(function()
            {
                    var 
                       value = $j(this).find('td:last').text(),
                       number = parseInt(value);
                    if (!isNaN(number) && number < 0) {
                        $(this).addClass('background')    
                    }
            });
    });
```